# AWS Cognito create user in user pool while facebook or google authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to add user to user pool if user authenticates using facebook or google?
I need this because I want simple logout and init current user. If I won't use user pool then I will have to init and logout users using facebook and google sdk.

Comment: Did you get any insights?